# Proving two reflections across a line are commutative if and only if the two lines are perpendicular

Tags: geometry, reflection

Please note brackets () denote inner product - for some reason the traditional symbols for inner product do not show up when I type them in!

Hi,

I am trying to prove that the two reflections in $\mathbf{R}^2$, defined:

$$\begin{align}
\Omega_\ell &= X-2(X-P,N)N \\
\Omega_m &= X-2(X-Q,N^\prime)N^\prime
\end{align}$$

Commute if and only if the lines $\ell$ and $m$ are perpendicular.

$$\Omega_\ell \circ \Omega_m = \Omega_m \circ \Omega_\ell$$

Using the two algebraic definitions above and simplifying, and then setting the two results equal, I find this implies:

$$\begin{align}
4(X-P,N)(N,N^\prime)N^\prime &= 4(X-Q,N^\prime)(N,N^\prime)N \\[4pt]
\quad\implies\quad(X-P,N)(N,N^\prime)N^\prime &=\phantom{4}(X-Q,N^\prime)(N,N^\prime)N 
\end{align}$$

I've tried everything I can think of to prove that this is true if and only if $\ell$ and $m$ are perpendicular (and thus $N$ and $N^\prime$ are perpendicular). I've tried proof by contraction (assume $N$ and $N^\prime$ aren't perpendicular, ie. $(N,N^\prime) \neq 0$) but haven't gotten anywhere. It is trivial to prove that they are equal (ie. both $0$) if $N$ and $N^\prime$ are perpendicular, but this does not show that this must be the case.

Any help on this problem would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course, the reflections about the same line also commute.

Comment: Pick some orthonormal basis, so that we can regard the transformations as orthogonal matrices. Now, if two matrices commute (and at least one has no repeated eigenvalues), then the matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable, so they fix each other's eigenspaces. But the eigenvalues of a reflection $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are $+1, -1$, and the eigenspaces are the line $\ell$ of reflection (+1) and its orthogonal $\ell^{\perp}$ (-1). So, the only reflections that commute with $R$ are the reflection through $\ell$ and the reflection through $\ell^{\perp}$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the two lines were distinct.

I believe your answer may be a little beyond the scope of my course. However, how do we turn a general reflection into an orthogonal matrix? I thought only reflection around the origin has a matrix representation (ie. because it is linear).