# Commutative reflections in the plane

Tags: geometry, reflection

How can i show formally that two reflections $S_v ,S_w$  in the plane commute iff $v=±w$ or v and w are orthogonal.
I tried and searched a lot, but did not manage to prove this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006924/proving-two-reflections-across-a-line-are-commutative-if-and-only-if-the-two-lin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S_vv=-v$ and $v$ is the only such (unit) vector up to sign. Then

$$S_vS_wv=S_wS_vv=-S_wv$$ so either $S_wv=0$ or $S_wv=\pm v$ by the above.

If $S_wv=0$ then $v\perp w$ since eigenvectors of reflections are orthogonal.
If $S_wv=\pm v$ then $v=\pm w$, again by the above uniqueness, for $S_w$.

Comment: Thanks, for solving this we can only take areflection $S_v$, $S_w$ in the point $v$ specifically? Why is $S_w(v)=0$ , i didn't get this using the formula of a reflection.

Comment: @Almaa The condition for an eigenvector is that it is non-zero. So either $S_wv$ is zero or it is proportional to $v$. I don't understand your question. You can also start with $S_vS_ww$ instead and get the same result.

Comment: Okay, i mean in which cases $S_v(w)=0$ , i did not understand how it ia connected to eignvectos